# How can I overload functions with generic parameters in scala

Tags: scala, overloading, seq

I just want to overload seq in a function, like:

```
insertBatch(sql: String, params: Seq[Seq[String]])
insertBatch(sql: String, params: Seq[Map[String,String]])
```

But always hint me that "insertBatch(String, Seq) is already defined in scope".
So I try to use "Any":

```
insertBatch(sql: String, params: Seq[Any])
```

This can be defined, but how can I use this params in the function?
such as:

```
def insertBatch(sql: String, params: Seq[Any]){
    ......
    for( param <- params) {
        // when param is a map?
        for( p <- param) {
            ...
        }
        // when param is a seq? 
        param.get("some Key")
        ...
    }
    ......
}
```

Scala is just a new language for me, Any help?

Comment: The thing is that all type-parameters are erased at runtime (this is called `type erasure`) and that is the reason for type-parameters being ignored for determining the signature of a method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Method overloading over generic types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982552/scala-method-overloading-over-generic-types)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov pamu's answers is better choice for this question.

Comment: Someone came and down-voted all the answers on this question (even pamu's which looks like a great answer to me) without a comment. That is just awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the type erasure of the JVM the above two methods are indistinguishable by the JVM at runtime. The general way to deal with type erasure issues is `TypeTag`. You may use `classTag` as well but `classTag` is limited.

So, Instead of declaring two methods, declare one method with type parameter `T` and at runtime figure out what `T` is and proceed.

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def insertBatch[T: TypeTag](sql: String, params: Seq[T]): Unit = typeOf[T] match {
    case a if  a =:= typeOf[Seq[String]] =>
      val l = params.asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]]
      // do something here
    case b if b =:= typeOf[Map[String, String]] =>
      val l = params.asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, String]]]
      // do something here
    case _ => //some other types
  }
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def insertBatch[T: TypeTag](sql: String, params: Seq[T]): Unit = typeOf[T] match {
    case a if  a =:= typeOf[Seq[String]] =>
      val l = params.asInstanceOf[Seq[Seq[String]]]
      println("bar")
    case b if b =:= typeOf[Map[String, String]] =>
      val l = params.asInstanceOf[Seq[Map[String, String]]]
      println("foo")
    case _ => println("ignore")
  }



// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
insertBatch: [T](sql: String, params: Seq[T])(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])Unit

scala> insertBatch[Seq[String]]("", Seq(Seq("")))
bar

scala> insertBatch[Map[String, String]]("", Seq(Map.empty[String, String]))
foo

scala> insertBatch[String]("", Seq(""))
ignore
```

Comment: These solved my problem! thx~~ Never heard runtimeUniverse package

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that all `type parameters` are erased at runtime (`type erasure`)  hence `type parameters` are ignored ored for determining the signature of a method.

Now lets comeback to your requirement, you want your function to behave differently for `Seq[Seq[String]]` and `Seq[Map[String,String]]`. You will have to change it in a way so that the "type hint" is included by the compiler.

```
def insertBatch[T](sql: String, params: Seq[T]){
  for( param <- params) {
    param match {
      // when param is a map?
      case _: Map[_, _] => for(key <- param.keys) {
        ...
      }
      // when param is a seq?
      case _: Seq[_] => for( p <- param) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have try your code, that's helpful too! And by this way, I don't need import other package, These is better answer!

Comment: Actually @pamu's answer will be better for this particular problem. And `scala.reflect.runtime.universe` is part of `scala` itself. So you are not using anything external.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a discriminated union instead of `Any`, for example:

```
def insertBatch[T](sql: String, params: Seq[Either[Seq[String], Map[String, String]]]) =
  params foreach {
    case Left(seq) => ...
    case Right(map) => ...
  }
```

This makes clear your intent in the type, doesn't suffer from type erasure issues, and doesn't violate [parametricity](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/09/22/parametricity-money-for-nothing-and-theorems-for-free/).

Comment: I have try this way, found that this is fine for defined a function, but I cannot use this function, because the input "params" should be "Seq[Either]" type. thx all the same~