# Why does DummyImplicit not disambiguate [String](a: A) from (a: String)

Tags: scala, type-erasure, implicits

Given the following piece of code:

```
final case class Attr[A](name: String)(implicit conv: String To A) {
  def apply(value: A)(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit) = Attribute(name, value)
  def apply(value: String) = Attribute[A](name, value)
}
```

The Scala compiler complains with "ambiguous reference to overloaded definition" when it sees the values hereafter:

```
1| val FooAttr = Attr[String]("foo")
2| val catch22 = FooAttr("bar")
```

Line 1: My intent is it to pass to the factory "Attr" producing "Attributes" the value type "String" as well as the name "foo" for all the attributes it ever produces.

Line 2: Using the previously configured attribute factory I am actually producing an attribute named "foo" with the value "bar" of type "String".

My conclusion: Because the parameterized type "A" for this factory object is "String" the Scala compiler deduces the same parameter signatures of method "apply" being "(value: String)" which are ambiguous. Therefore I tried to make a difference in signature by adding an implicit parameter list.

After having read an article about [type erasure and DummyImplicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422336/how-can-i-differentiate-between-def-fooaxs-a-and-def-fooa-bxs-a-b) and consulting the Scala reference section "7.2 Implicit parameters" **I thought "(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit)" would do the trick**.

For the moment my solution is to have the minimal wrapper:

```
final case class Txt(str: String) {
  override def toString = str
}
```

Given that an implicit value of type "Str To Txt", i.e. a suitable conversion function, could be found, the second line from above compiles, i.e.:

```
2| val catch22 = FooAttr("bar")
```

It seems I was thinking too complicated. Instead to overload the `apply` method with a parameter list of `(value: String)`, I simply got rid of it. The version that lives up to my full expectations now looks like:

```
final case class Attr[A](name: String)(implicit conv: String To A) {
  def apply(value: A) = Attribute(name, value)
}
```

Comment: Could you post a reduced, self-contained code sample that shows the error message you're getting? I don't quite understand your intent.

Comment: Also: In the answer to the Stack Overflow question you linked, retronym states: *Please consider this as a opportunity to learn about erasure, context bounds and implicit search, rather than as a pattern to be applied in real code!* Maybe there's a simpler way to achieve what you need.

Comment: I updated the article to make my intentions and conclusions clearer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
case class Attribute[A](name: String, value: A)

case class AttrBuilder[A](name: String)(implicit conv: String => A) {
  def apply[B](value: B)(implicit conv: B => A) = Attribute(name, conv(value))
}

val bldr = new AttrBuilder[String]("MyAttrs")

bldr("hello") // Attribute(MyAttrs, hello)

implicit def int2string(x: Int) = x.toString
bldr(2)       // Attribute(MyAttrs, 2), using int2string implicit

bldr(false)   // fails; cannot find implicit Boolean => String
```

The attribute builder `bldr` will take any value of type `B` that's convertable to `A == String`, including strings themselves (the implicit conversion `Predef.conforms` is used in that case).

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your reply. Although I would like to see my sample code given in the original post work, my foremost interest is the question, why the Scala compiler does not make a difference when it finds a second parameter list which is implicit and a value of type DummyImplicit is found in Predef.

Comment: Now, regarding your proposal: Unfortunately the `AttrBuilder` is too general. By parameterizing it with the type `String` its `apply` method should accept either values of source type `String` converting a given value to target type `A` or accepting a value of target type `A` right away.

Comment: I found a solution that satisfies my demands. See the end of my original post.