# What is the Scala identifier "implicitly"?

Tags: scala, implicits

I have seen a function named `implicitly` used in Scala examples. What is it, and how is it used?

[Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307427/scala-double-definition-2-methods-have-the-same-type-erasure/3798426#3798426):

```
scala> sealed trait Foo[T] { def apply(list : List[T]) : Unit }; object Foo {
     |                         implicit def stringImpl = new Foo[String] {
     |                             def apply(list : List[String]) = println("String")
     |                         }
     |                         implicit def intImpl = new Foo[Int] {
     |                             def apply(list : List[Int]) =  println("Int")
     |                         }
     |                     } ; def foo[A : Foo](x : List[A]) = implicitly[Foo[A]].apply(x)
defined trait Foo
defined module Foo
foo: [A](x: List[A])(implicit evidence$1: Foo[A])Unit

scala> foo(1)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: List[?]
       foo(1)
           ^
scala> foo(List(1,2,3))
Int
scala> foo(List("a","b","c"))
String
scala> foo(List(1.0))
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type
 Foo[Double]
       foo(List(1.0))
          ^
```

Note that we have to write `implicitly[Foo[A]].apply(x)` since the compiler thinks that  `implicitly[Foo[A]](x)` means that we call `implicitly` with parameters.

Also see [How to investigate objects/types/etc. from Scala REPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11392622/203968) and [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Here are a few reasons to use the delightfully simple method `implicitly`.

### To understand/troubleshoot Implicit Views

An Implicit View can be triggered when the prefix of a selection (consider for example, `the.prefix.selection(args)` does not contain a member `selection` that is applicable to `args` (even after trying to convert `args` with Implicit Views). In this case, the compiler looks for implicit members, locally defined in the current or enclosing scopes, inherited, or imported, that are either Functions from the type of that `the.prefix` to a type with `selection` defined, or equivalent implicit methods.

```
scala> 1.min(2) // Int doesn't have min defined, where did that come from?                                   
res21: Int = 1

scala> implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]
res22: (Int) => AnyRef{def min(i: Int): Any} = <function1>

scala> res22(1) // 
res23: AnyRef{def min(i: Int): Int} = 1

scala> .getClass
res24: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.runtime.RichInt
```

Implicit Views can also be triggered when an expression does not conform to the Expected Type, as below:

```
scala> 1: scala.runtime.RichInt
res25: scala.runtime.RichInt = 1
```

Here the compiler looks for this function:

```
scala> implicitly[Int => scala.runtime.RichInt]
res26: (Int) => scala.runtime.RichInt = <function1>
```

### Accessing an Implicit Parameter Introduced by a Context Bound

Implicit parameters are arguably a more important feature of Scala than Implicit Views. They support the type class pattern. The standard library uses this in a few places -- see `scala.Ordering` and how it is used in `SeqLike#sorted`. Implicit Parameters are also used to pass Array manifests, and `CanBuildFrom` instances.

Scala 2.8 allows a shorthand syntax for implicit parameters, called Context Bounds. Briefly, a method with a type parameter `A` that requires an implicit parameter of type `M[A]`:

```
def foo[A](implicit ma: M[A])
```

can be rewritten as:

```
def foo[A: M]
```

But what's the point of passing the implicit parameter but not naming it? How can this be useful when implementing the method `foo`?

Often, the implicit parameter need not be referred to directly, it will be tunneled through as an implicit argument to another method that is called. If it is needed, you can still retain the terse method signature with the Context Bound, and call `implicitly` to materialize the value:

```
def foo[A: M] = {
   val ma = implicitly[M[A]]
}
```

### Passing a subset of implicit parameters explicitly

Suppose you are calling a method that pretty prints a person, using a type class based approach:

```
trait Show[T] { def show(t: T): String }
object Show {
  implicit def IntShow: Show[Int] = new Show[Int] { def show(i: Int) = i.toString }
  implicit def StringShow: Show[String] = new Show[String] { def show(s: String) = s }

  def ShoutyStringShow: Show[String] = new Show[String] { def show(s: String) = s.toUpperCase }
}

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
object Person {
  implicit def PersonShow(implicit si: Show[Int], ss: Show[String]): Show[Person] = new Show[Person] {
    def show(p: Person) = "Person(name=" + ss.show(p.name) + ", age=" + si.show(p.age) + ")"
  }
}

val p = Person("bob", 25)
implicitly[Show[Person]].show(p)
```

What if we want to change the way that the name is output? We can explicitly call `PersonShow`, explicitly pass an alternative `Show[String]`, but we want the compiler to pass the `Show[Int]`.

```
Person.PersonShow(si = implicitly, ss = Show.ShoutyStringShow).show(p)
```

Comment: scala> 1.min(2)
res0: Int = 1

In Scala 2.10.3 I get an error:scala> implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]
<console>:8: error: No implicit view available from Int => AnyRef{def min(i: Int): Any}.
              implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]

Comment: This answer would be updated for the latest version.

Comment: implicitly[Int => AnyVal{ def min(i: Int): Int }] will work. Should be fixed in the answer.

Answer (score 223):

`implicitly` is avaliable in Scala 2.8 and is  defined in [Predef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html) as:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

It is commonly used to **check if an implicit *value* of type `T` is available and return it** if such is the case.

Simple example  from [retronym's presentation](http://vimeo.com/15264203):

```
scala> implicit val a = "test" // define an implicit value of type String
a: java.lang.String = test
scala> val b = implicitly[String] // search for an implicit value of type String and assign it to b
b: String = test
scala> val c = implicitly[Int] // search for an implicit value of type Int and assign it to c
<console>:6: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Int
       val c = implicitly[Int]
                         ^
```

Comment: The method doesn't exactly check; it seems to cause a compile error if there isn't an implicit value available and, if there is, seems to retrieve it.  Can you provide some more context on why I'd ever want to use this?

Comment: `implicitly[Ordering[(Int, String)]].compare( (1, "b"), (1, "a") )`, especially to retrieve an implicit parameter introduced by a Context Bound: `def foo[A: Ordering](a1: A, a2: A) = implicitly[Ordering[A]].compare(a1, a2)`

Comment: To see retronym's discussion in the video link above, skip to the point 13:50.

Answer (score 4):

Starting Scala 3 `implicitly` has been replaced with improved `summon` which has the advantage of being able to return a more [precise type](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html#using-clauses) than asked for

> The `summon` method corresponds to implicitly in Scala 2. It is
> precisely the same as the the method in Shapeless. The difference
> between `summon` (or the) and `implicitly` is that summon can return a
> more precise type than the type that was asked for.

For example given the following type

```
trait F[In]:
  type Out
  def f(v: Int): Out

given F[Int] with 
  type Out = String
  def f(v: Int): String = v.toString
```

`implicitly` method would summon a term with erased type member `Out`

```
scala> implicitly[F[Int]]
val res5: F[Int] = given_F_Int$@7d0e5fbb

scala> implicitly[res5.Out =:= String]
1 |implicitly[res5.Out =:= String]
  |                               ^
  |                               Cannot prove that res5.Out =:= String.

scala> val x: res5.Out = ""
1 |val x: res5.Out = ""
  |                  ^^
  |                  Found:    ("" : String)
  |                  Required: res5.Out
```

In order to recover the type member we would have to refer to it explicitly which defeats the purpose of having the type member instead of type parameter

```
scala> implicitly[F[Int] { type Out = String }]
val res6: F[Int]{Out = String} = given_F_Int$@7d0e5fbb

scala> implicitly[res6.Out =:= String]
val res7: res6.Out =:= String = generalized constraint
```

However [`summon`](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/c57aa0a1174e8173d5a56d9bd188f53c9e522940/library/src/scala/runtime/stdLibPatches/Predef.scala#L34) defined as

```
def summon[T](using inline x: T): x.type = x
```

does not suffer from this problem

```
scala> summon[F[Int]]
val res8: given_F_Int.type = given_F_Int$@7d0e5fbb

scala> summon[res8.Out =:= String]
val res9: String =:= String = generalized constraint

scala> val x: res8.Out = ""
val x: res8.Out = ""
```

where we see type member `type Out = String` did not get erased even though we only asked for `F[Int]` and not `F[Int] { type Out = String }`. This can prove particularly relevant when [chaining dependently typed functions](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide/blob/110d34792457e1edccb9f9361a3074a1a6640df9/src/pages/type-level-programming/dependent-functions.md#L88):

> The type summoned by implicitly has no `Out` type member. For this
> reason, we should avoid implicitly when working with dependently typed
> functions.

Answer (score -4):

A "teach you to fish" answer is to use the alphabetic member index currently available in the [Scaladoc nightlies](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html). The letters (and the `#`, for non-alphabetic names) at the top of the package / class pane are links to the index for member names beginning with that letter (across all classes). If you choose `I`, e.g., you'll find the `implicitly` entry with one occurrence, in `Predef`, which you can visit from the link there.

Comment: Of course, those scaladocs say nothing at all about implicitly, so that hardly counts as documentation.  How would someone figure out what that method does from those docs alone?  I feel routinely let down by the Scala documentation.  The behavior of methods like implicitly are far from obvious, and the documentation on them is barely better than nonexistent.  Thank god for Stack Overflow.  /end rant

Comment: @Jeff see http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Best-way-to-contribute-documentation-improvements-td2314020.html

Comment: The type signature documents this one pretty well.

Comment: `implicit` appears to be an important language-feature in Scala, and definitely worthy of proper explanation. Thinking that docs detailing only a type-signature count seems more like intellectual self-gratification, than a genuine answer. **See the specific questions asked by the OP -- what is it, and how is it used?** Neither answered by this, or in the nightly docs which you don't even provide an actual link to. http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Predef$  This doesn't teach anything. See Niklaus Wirth or Turbo Pascal for examples of genuine docs. -1

Comment: `implicit` and `implicitly` are related, but quite distinct. The `implicit` keyword is part of the language. `implicitly` is defined in plain Scala code in the standard library. Since the on-line docs include source links, I believe it's still best to refer questioners to those documents and the linked source.