# How to use implicitly to find a conversion to a type with a method name?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

In another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/scala-identifier-implicitly) they give the following code example:

```
scala> implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]
res22: (Int) => AnyRef{def min(i: Int): Any} = <function1>
```

That doesn't work in my scala console (2.10.0-RC2).

```
scala> implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]
<console>:8: error: No implicit view available from Int => AnyRef{def min(i: Int): Any}.
          implicitly[Int => { def min(i: Int): Any }]
                    ^
scala> 12 min 11
res15: Int = 11
```

What is the new way to do it?  And what does that syntax mean anyway? I'm not familiar with it -- specifically the part `{ def min(i: Int): Any }`, used as a type expression. Is that defining an anonymous type of some kind?

I want to do this because I'd like to track down an implicit conversion when I see it in code and have no idea where it is imported from.  For example, the other day I saw some code that was calling `format` on a `java.util.Date`, which doesn't have `format`.  I didn't know which import pulled in the conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to find `min` because `RichInt` is a value class now (which doesn't work with structural typing--that has to be an `AnyRef`).

But the strategy will work otherwise:

```
scala> implicitly[Option[Int] => { def iterator: Iterator[Int] }]
res29: Option[Int] => AnyRef{def iterator: Iterator[Int]} = <function1>
```

So the same trick will work, just not with value classes.  Try an IDE instead.

Comment: I haven't really been keeping up with the state of the union regarding Scala 2.10 (and, by extension, value classes), so I don't know how this relates there, but, as it turns out, the claim that the target of structural typing has to be an `AnyRef` is actually not true—at least not in 2.9.x.  A trivial counterexample: `def anyValToString[T <: AnyVal { def toString: String }](t: T) : String = t.toString`.  As the type here suggests, this method will only work with `AnyVal`s as inputs.

Comment: @Destin - Interesting.  Pre-value-class, all (non-specialized) generics were actually `Object`s under the hood, even if you were using boxed `AnyVal` versions, so allowing structural typing makes sense.  I guess you could box value classes also; I wonder why that isn't done?