# Scala implicit context resolution

Tags: scala, implicits

I have found there rules for implicict resolution i SLS:

1. if T is a compound type T1 with ... with Tn, the union of the parts of
   T1, ..., Tn, as well as T itself
2. if T is a parameterized type S[T1, ..., Tn], the union of the parts of S and
   T1, ..., Tn
3. if T is a singleton type p.type, the parts of the type of p
4. if T is a type projection S#U, the parts of S as well as T itself
5. in all other cases, just T itself

Is example below implicit resolution based on rule 4?

```
object Foo{
   trait Bar
   implicit def newBar = new Bar{
        override def toString = "Implicit Bar"
   }

}

implicitly[Foo.Bar]
```

Thanks

Zlaja

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773964/how-does-implicitly-work-in-this-example-from-scala-in-depth which probably means there are other duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that is correct. I think for a singleton object `Foo`, type `Foo.Bar` is the same as `Foo.type#Bar`:

```
implicitly[Foo.type#Bar] // ok
```

Also:

```
def a(f: Foo.type#Bar) {}
def b(f: Foo.Bar) { a(f) }       // accepted

def c(f: Foo.Bar) {}
def d(f: Foo.type#Bar) { c(f) }  // accepted
```