# REPL could not find implicit

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, read-eval-print-loop

Hi I have an implicit method like:

```
implicit def strToOpt(str: String): Option[String] = Option(str)
```

and it works for simple conversion, but when I type

```
implicitly[String]
```

I get

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: String
```

Does REPL have some limitations in term of finding implicits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the Scala identifier "implicitly"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/what-is-the-scala-identifier-implicitly)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood `implicitly`. It is defined as:

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T): T = e
```

Which roughly means, that `implicitly[T]` will return you an object of type `T` which is available in current scope (scope is not the precise word. Compiler looks at many [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits))

In your case doing `implicitly[String]` simply means that some object of type `String` is available.

For example this is valid:

```
scala> implicit val x = "Hey"
x: String = Hey

scala> implicitly[String]
res12: String = Hey
```

But what you rather need to do is:

```
scala> implicitly[(String) => Option[String]]
res10: String => Option[String] = <function1>

scala> res10("asd")
res11: Option[String] = Some(456)
```

PS: Note answer by @Ende Neu works as:

```
implicitly[Option[String]]("123")
```

Doing `implicitly[Option[String]]("123")`, in the implicitly function it takes `T` as argument which is `String`. But you have manually provided `Option[String]` as type parameter of method. So the compiler searches for a function again (by using `implicitly` again) that does `String => Option[String]` which it finds in your function.

Comment: I think I got it simultaneously to you posting this answer :) I have been having problems with forgeting this quirks recently. Need more coding I guess.