# Scala casting a number to Numeric[T] type

Tags: scala

I'm trying create a histogram class by extending a mutable hash map, the Key type could be anything while the counter type has to be a number(int, float, long etc). Also I'd like the default value to be zero.

I was able to implement it using this piece of code:

```
 class histogram[KEY, COUNT: Numeric] extends scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[KEY, COUNT] {

     /** Returns zero if a key does not exist*/
     override def default(key: KEY) = {
         zero()
     }

     def zero()(implicit n: Numeric[COUNT]) = {
         n.zero
     }
}
```

I can't find a better way to generate a zero of type `COUNT`, can't move `(implicit n: Numeric[COUNT])` after `default(key: KEY)` since it would no longer override.

Is there a better way to implement it?

How can I create an instance of `scala.Numeric[COUNT]` without using the `(implicit n: Numeric[COUNT])` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `A: TypeClass` (also known as context-bound) is a short cut for asking for an implicit parameter `implicit aTpe: TypeClass[A]`. You can recover that parameter in the first notation [using `implicitly[TypeClass[A]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/what-is-the-scala-identifier-implicitly), or just use the latter syntax.

```
class histogram[KEY, COUNT: Numeric] 
  extends scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[KEY, COUNT] {

  def zero() = implicitly[Numeric[COUNT]].zero
}
```

or (equivalent)

```
class histogram[KEY, COUNT](implicit numeric: Numeric[COUNT]) 
  extends scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[KEY, COUNT] {

  def zero() = numeric.zero
}
```