# could not find implicit value for parameter e

Tags: scala, implicit

```
case class Cat(name: String)

object CuterImplicits {
  implicit class CatCuteChecker(c: Cat) {
    def isCute(c: Cat) = true
  }
}

trait CuteChecker[A] {
  def isCute(a: A): Boolean
}

object CheckingForCuteness {
  def isItCute[A](a: A) = implicitly[CuteChecker[A]].isCute(a)
}

object Main extends App {
  CheckingForCuteness.isItCute[Cat](Cat("funny"))
}
```

how to fix:

> Error:(17, 37) could not find implicit value for parameter e:
>   CuteChecker[A]   def isItCute[A](a: A) =
>   implicitly[CuteChecker[A]].isCute(a)
>                                       ^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `implicitly` that simply makes [a value implicitly in scope "explicitly" available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/what-is-the-scala-identifier-implicitly). So your `isItCute` method should be either of the following two variants:

```
def isItCute[A: CuteChecker](a: A) = implicitly[CuteChecker[A]].isCute(a)

def isItCute[A](a: A)(implicit cc: CuteChecker[A]) = cc.isCute(a)
```

Next you want an implicit instance for `Cat`. The `implicit class` doesn't help you here because it requires a non-implicit value of type `Cat`. You can see that this approach is wrong because the constructor parameter is never used. You can use an `implicit object`:

```
implicit object CatCuteChecker extends CuteChecker[Cat] {
  def isCute(c: Cat) = true
}
```

Finally, you provide implicits in object `CuterImplicits`. For them to be visible to `Main`, you need to [import the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits):

```
object Main extends App {
  import CuterImplicits._
  CheckingForCuteness.isItCute[Cat](Cat("funny"))
}
```

Comment: question please in `isItCute` in main I pass an object of type `Cat`.  The signature of `def isItCute[A: CuteChecker](a: A)` is receiving an `a` which it says is of type `[A: CuteChecker]` so it looks like it wants to receive a `CuteChecker` unless I don't understand what `A: Cutechecker` means.  how can I receive a different type from `Cat`? i don't see i have any conversion between them all i have is an implicit CuteChecker for Cat

Comment: `def foo[A: Bar](x: A)` is syntactic sugar for `def foo[A](x: A)(implicit bar: Bar[A])`. If you want a `CuteChecker` for a type different than `Cat` you will have to define one and bring it into scope just like `CatCuteChecker`.

Answer (score 0):

There a multiple problems in your situation. The `implicitly` call expects an instance of the `CuteChecker` trait, while `CatCuteChecker` is neither an instance nor does not it extend this trait. Furthermore, the `c` class parameter is completely unnecessary.

You can fix your problem by declaring that subtyping relationship and providing an `implicit` *value*:

```
object CuterImplicits
{
    class CatCuteChecker with CuteChecker
    {
        def isCute(c: Cat) = true
    }

    implicit val catCuteChecker = new CatCuteChecker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implicits have to be visible ***unqualified*** at the point of invocation.
Different ways that implicits can become visible is best described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/843348.

It is also not completely clear what you are trying to achieve
and there are a number of possible ways to achieve something *like* the example.

One possibility is monkey patching Cat using an implicit class:

```
case class Cat(name: String)

object CuteImplicits {
  implicit class CuteCat(c: Cat){
    def isCute = true
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  import CuteImplicits._
  Cat("funny").isCute
}
```

You put implicits in the companion object of an associated type and the it is visible automatically.

```
case class Cat(name: String)

object Cat {
  implicit class CuteCat(c: Cat){
    def isCute = true
  }
}

object Main extends App {
  Cat("funny").isCute
}
```

In minimal example like this it not clear why you would not build the functionality directly into `Cat`.