# How do I guarantee that I am using not the default/global implicit context

Tags: scala, akka, future

I have a scala file that has this import

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
```

This works fine as the `Future` I am using works fine in my methods in that file. However, I have created a separate method that will be used for disk IO and I have a new execution context. I want this method to use this context while other methods can continue to use the default context. How do I guarantee that? I currently do this as follows

`private def testContext():Future[Int]  = {
   val system = ActorSystem.create()
   implicit val myexecutionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("blocking-io-dispatcher.db-backup-context")
   Future{logger.error("inside my new thread pool wonderland");10}{myexecutionContext}`

Is there a way without specifying the "myexecutionContext" like this at the end of each Future call, I can make this method still use "myexecutionContext" for all Future calls? In short, I do not want to be specifying "myexecutionContext" again and again as a parameter inside my "testContext" method. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify `myexecutionContext` inside `testContext()`. `myexecutionContext` is defined inside `testContext()`, which takes precedence over the `global` context imported outside the method. All `Future`s created in `testContext()` will use `myexecutionContext` by default.

Comment: Is this because I have declared it as "implicit" inside my method? What if I declare ``myexecutionContext``  as ``val ..`` instead of ``implicit val``. Also is there a way to verify which pool was used for executing the ``Future`` just for my own satisfaction?

Comment: You need to declare it as `implicit val` for it to be used as an implicit parameter. Otherwise the global one will be used. For verification, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517712/in-scala-is-there-a-way-to-tell-which-execution-context-you-are-running-in

Comment: yes thanks for the help, I just did the same ``Thread.currentThread.getName`` like we do in Java and I am getting the name of my context. One last question is why does it prepend the word "default" before it in my log. Here is what I see in the log
``inside my new thread pool wonderland and context is default-blocking-io-dispatcher.db-backup-context-7``

Comment: Am not super familiar with Akka dispatchers, it may involve something that is undefined (maybe `blocking-io-dispatcher` doesn't exist?) but it's just a wild guess.

Comment: I am using play and I create that in the ``application.conf``
``blocking-io-dispatcher {
    db-backup-context {
      thread-pool-executor {
        core-pool-size-factor = 10.0
        core-pool-size-max = 10
      }
    }``