# Supplying implicit argument EXPLICITLY

Tags: scala

I have a function like this:

```
case class SomeCaseClass(i: Int)

def func[T: Manifest](someArg: Int)(implicit i: String) = {
  SomeCaseClass(2)
}
```

I need to call `func` and supply `i` **explicitly**

but when I call `func[SomeCaseClass](2)("hello")`, I get:

> error: not enough arguments for method func: (implicit   evidence$1:
>   Manifest[ScalaFiddle.this.SomeCaseClass], implicit  i:
>   String)ScalaFiddle.this.SomeCaseClass. Unspecified value parameter i. 
>   funcSomeCaseClass("hello")

Any way to do it without changing the function's signature?

Comment: Do you have the real signature (assuming this is a simplified example)? What is the manifest being used for?

Comment: In the actual case, the function calls `jValue.extract[T]` of `org.json4s.ExtractableJsonAstNode`. This function's signature is  `def extract[A](implicit formats: Formats, mf: scala.reflect.Manifest[A]): A`. In any case, this is part of out infrastructure code, and I am very reluctant to change it.

Comment: As a side note, having an implicit `string` is not a great idea... although I realize you may have simplified the type for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give *all* implicit parameters explicitly if you give any, and `T: Manifest` means there is an additional implicit parameter.

Happily, [`implicitly` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855595/what-is-the-scala-identifier-implicitly) will summon the implicit which the compiler would have supplied:

```
func[SomeCaseClass](2)(implicitly, "hello") // inferred to implicitly[Manifest[SomeCaseClass]]
```

Comment: should i need to import anything here ? i'm getting compiler error and my scala version is 2.11

Comment: No, you shouldn't, it's in `Predef`. Do you get an error with `implicitly[Manifest[SomeCaseClass]]`? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: Type mismatch, expected: Manifest[SomeCaseClass], actual: CanBuildFrom[String, Char, String]

Comment: There's no `CanBuildFrom` involved in your example code. Obviously if you have different types there you'll need to adjust. You can see it working at https://scalafiddle.io/sf/EYro2yQ/0.

Comment: i'm not really sure why i'm getting this error.  but this is not stopping me from running the code and getting the result...

Answer (score 0):

When I define the method `func` in my scala REPL, I am finding the output as:

```
func: [T](someArg: Int)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T], implicit i: String)SomeCaseClass
```

In other words, the same code can also be written as:

```
def func1[T](someArg: Int)(implicit manifest: Manifest[T], i: String) = {
  SomeCaseClass(2)
}
```

It is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3213914/5942145) as well.

So in the above code, we can see that the `implicit` section now have two parameters, not the only `String`. And you need to provide all the params of the `implicit` section in case you want to fill them explicitly. If you're providing just one it will throw a compilation error.

Hence your method `func` can be called through the below code:

```
func(2)(Manifest.classType(classOf[SomeCaseClass]), "hello")
```