# is "implictly" in scala now deprecated or at least not required anymore?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, fs2

checking into fs2 tutorial, I stumbled upon the following code

```
def client[F[_]: MonadCancelThrow: Console: Network]: F[Unit] =
  Network[F].client(SocketAddress(host"localhost", port"5555")).use { socket =>
    socket.write(Chunk.array("Hello, world!".getBytes)) >>
      socket.read(8192).flatMap { response =>
        Console[F].println(s"Response: $response")
      }
  }
```

where

```
Network[F].client
```

felt wierd as i would notmally write

```
implictly[Network[F]].client
```

So i checked the code and it work and compile, so it must be that implicitly is not required anymore. I wonder since when ? is it going to be deprecated ? Can someone share the link to the scala release notes or something that state that ?

Comment: `implicitly` method has been [replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143077/5205022) with `summon` in Scala 3.

Comment: @MarioGalic thanks for the answer and my apologies for not specifying that this was a scala 2 specific question. Good to know in advance tho !!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a convention followed by many libraries: if `FooBar[K]` is some typeclass, then one usually defines an `apply` method on the companion object, with a signature that looks somewhat like this:

```
object FooBar {
  def apply[K](implicit ev: FooBar[K]): FooBar[K] = ev
}
```

or maybe (if one wants to have a more precise type, in particular if one wants to [have access to type members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143077/2707792) of `ev`), like this:

```
object FooBar {
  def apply[K](implicit ev: FooBar[K]): ev.type = ev
}
```

thereby allowing to write down value-level expressions that look exactly like the type of the expression:

```
FooBar[K]: FooBar[K] // desugars into FooBar.apply[F](<implicit instance>)
```

Here is this method in `Network` ([link to github](https://github.com/typelevel/fs2/blob/main/io/src/main/scala/fs2/io/net/Network.scala#L103), comments are mine):

```
def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Network[F]): F.type = F
//        ^--- type-constructor
//                       ^--- value
//                                  ^--- type-constructor
//                                       ^--- value
//                                                ^--- value
```

This convention is independent of and mostly unaffected by the `implicitly`/`summon` change in Scala 3.

Comment: Right, thanks for making that explicit :)

Comment: I think you have a typo here `def apply[K](implicitly ev: FooBar[K]): FooBar[K] = ev` it should use implicit instead of implictly no, for the parameter.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Oh, yeah, indeed, I was `using` the method name instead of the proper keyword... Thanks, fixed.

Comment: It can be a bit more than convention if the apply summoner returns more precise type with .type than implicitly.

Answer (score 6):

`implicitly` isn't deprecated.

There is a pattern, generally seen in the typelevel ecosystem, of which fs2 is one, of having the `apply` method in the companion object be a synonym for `implicitly`, which allows user code to not use `implicitly`.