# What is the use of `*.this` in Scala?

Tags: scala, path-dependent-type

```
class S {
  case class A(a: Int)
}

abstract class R(val s: S) {
  type T1 = R.this.s.A
  type T2 = s.A
  implicitly[T1 =:= T2] // compiles

  type T3 = R.this.type
  type T4 = this.type
  implicitly[T3 =:= T4] // compiles

  val v1 = R.this //  v1 == `this`
  val v2 = R.this.s // v2 == `s`
}
```

Looks like the `.this` part has no effect whatsoever. To make a concrete question:
When do you use the `.this` ?

Comment: As in **Java** `this` is completely optional when is not ambiguous. The `R` is even lesser common since that is only needed when you need to disambiguate which parent class you want to access.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Would you then put some examples in an answer that clearly shows where it *is* ambiguous or more clear to use it ?

Comment: Sorry I am on cellphone and writing code is a nightmare. The classical example is a hand made setter which are very very weird. I sometimes like to use `this` when I receive another instance of the same class, while is not needed at all I like to make it more verbose and clear. - Hope someone will post a complete answer latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It matters for inner classes. E.g.

```scala
class Outer(val x: Int) {
  class Inner(val x: Int) {
    def outer_this = Outer.this.x
    def inner_this = this.x // or just x
  }
}

val outer = new Outer(0)
val inner = new outer.Inner(1)
println(inner.outer_this) // 0
println(inner.inner_this) // 1
```

Each `Outer.Inner` instances "belongs to" a specific `Outer` instance, and can refer to that instance as `Outer.this`. By itself `x` in `Inner` refers to its own property, so if you need the enclosing instance's `x` property, you write `Outer.this.x`.

Answer (score 2):

One rule is Scala never infers singleton type `this.type`. For example first consider the mechanics of it

```
scala> trait Foo {
     |   type T
     |   def f() = this // we left out the return type to see what Scala will infer
     | }
// defined trait Foo

scala> new Foo { type T = String }
val res0: Foo{T = String} = anon$1@6d3ad37a

scala> res0.f()
val res1: Foo = anon$1@6d3ad37a
```

Note how `res1` has return type of `Foo` and not `Foo { type T = String }`, so we have lost some type information

```
scala> val x: res1.T = ""
1 |val x: res1.T = ""
  |                ^^
  |                Found:    ("" : String)
  |                Required: res1.T
```

Note compiler does not know `res1.T` is actually a `String`. So compiler did not infer the singleton type `this.type` which would have all the type information including what type member `T` was instantiated to

```
scala> trait Foo {
     |   type T
     |   def f(): this.type = this
     | }
// defined trait Foo

scala> new Foo { type T = String }
val res2: Foo{T = String} = anon$1@7d381eae

scala> res2.f()
val res3: Foo{T = String} = anon$1@7d381eae

scala> val x: res3.T = ""
val x: res3.T = ""
```

Note how after we explicitly declared singleton return type `this.type` compiler knows `T` is a `String`.

Here is another mechanical example of what happens because compiler does not infer singleton type `this.type`

```
scala> trait Foo {
     |   def f() = this // let inference do its thing
     | }
// defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar {
     |   def g() = 42
     | }
// defined trait Bar

scala> trait Bar extends Foo {
     |   def g(): Int = 42
     | }
// defined trait Bar

scala> new Bar {}
val res5: Bar = anon$1@6a9a6a0c

scala> res5.f()
val res6: Foo = anon$1@6a9a6a0c

scala> res6.g()
1 |res6.g()
  |^^^^^^
  |value g is not a member of Foo
```

Note how `f()` call typed to `Foo` and not perhaps expected `Bar`. On the other hand if we provide explicit singleton return type `this.type` then

```
scala> trait Foo {
     |   def f(): this.type = this
     | }
// defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar extends Foo {
     |   def g(): Int = 42
     | }
// defined trait Bar

scala> new Bar {}
val res7: Bar = anon$1@4707d60a

scala> res7.f()
val res8: Bar = anon$1@4707d60a

scala> res8.g()
val res9: Int = 42
```

we see `f()` call typed to `Bar`.

Those were the mechanics but what about practical applications? Two uses I am aware of are:

- supporting [fluent](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-fluent-style-programming-methods-in-scala/) style of programming
- supporting [summoners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67382656/5205022) of type class instances (see also Scala 3 [summon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143077/5205022))

---