# Generic method bounded type parameter and type erasure

Tags: java, generics

A generic method as per below:

```
static <E, K extends E> void someMethod(K k, E[] e) {}
```

I presumed upon erasure, the erasure type would be:

```
static void someMethod(Object k, Object[] e) {}
```

Just curious how would the type parameter knows the constraints after type erasure? That type parameter K is bounded to E?

Answer (score 8):

You are correct about the erasure. Actually, the runtime doesn't know about the constraints. Only the compiler does.

Comment: Otherwise it wouldn't be very erased.

Answer (score 2):

Your type-erased signature is correct. However, the constraints of a method are not erased during compilation. They are encoded in metadata that is used at compile time (and not normally used at runtime although it can be accessed via reflection*). For example the class `java.util.ArrayList<E>` has the method:

```
public E get(int index)
```

Which with type-erasure becomes:

```
public Object get(int index)
```

However, in your code if you parameterize `ArrayList` with `String` then you will be to call the `get(...)` method without need to cast the result to a `String` despite the type-erasure.

This is different from what happens when you parameterize a class or method call. The provided parameterizations **are** completely erased at compile time. For example:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

After compilation is equivalent to:

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
```

---

*Accessing this information at run time via reflection can be done by using reflection methods which return `java.lang.reflect.Type` instances. For example, to get the constraints of your method at runtime you could call `java.lang.reflect.Method`'s `getGenericParameterTypes()` method. Processing this returned information would make it possible to determine the constraints at run time.

Answer (score 2):

I want to note that, in fact, your type constraint

```
static <E, K extends E> void someMethod(K k, E[] e) {}
```

has *exactly* the same effect (at compile time) as

```
static void someMethod(Object k, Object[] e) {}
```

Try calling `someMethod("foo", new Integer[3])` if you don't believe me.

This is because it is valid for the compiler to infer `Object` as the parameters for both `E` and `K` (since any `K` object is also an instance of `Object`, and any `E[]` object is also an instance of `Object[]` (remember that array types are covariant in Java)).

This is a common pitfall in Java Generics. For example, the `Arrays.fill()` method has the signature `static void fill(Object[] a, Object val)`; it is not possible for them to restrict it further.