# Scala type erasure issue with path dependent/nested types

Tags: scala

Let's assume the following:

```
class Wrapper1 {
  case class Condition(test: String)
}
object Wrapper1 extends Wrapper1

class Wrapper2 {
  case class Condition[A](test: String)
}
object Wrapper2 extends Wrapper2


class Test 
  type T = // whatever

  def test(fn: T => Wrapper1.Condition): X
  def test[R](fn: T => Wrapper2.Condition[R]): X
}
```

The problem is that because of type erasure those methods have the exact same type after erasure. It's easy to change the signature of the second with say:

```
def test[R](fn: T => Wrapper2.Condition[R])(implicit ev: R =:= R): X
```

But that confuses the compiler and using the `test` method in other places is impossible. For a number of design reasons I'm trying to keep the name of this method consistent. Is there any way to successfully do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to work it out. What I was after was a way to conditionally append to an `HList`. Basically multiple overloads of the same method had to co-exist because they would return a different kind of `HList`.

To only have one method, arguments needed to dictate what the final signature of the method looked like.

So let's assume the following, the `test` method had to return

```
def test[RR](arg: Type1[RR]): Wrapper[RR :: ExistingHList]
```

Or respectively:

```
def test(arg: Type2): Wrapper[ExistingList]
```

The same method would have to append to an `Hlist` depending on whether or not the argument satisfied certain conditions. The fix was as trivial as using `shapeless.ops.hlist.Prepend`, which will by default returning the existing `HList` in the event we try to append `HNil` to an hlist.

Making the argument of `Type2` return an `HNil` or implicitly convert to something that would end up being `HNil` was the approach that worked.

Specifically:

```
  class Wrapper[PS <: HList] {
    def test[
      RR,
      HL <: HList,
      Out <: HList
    ](
      condition: T => Wrapper[HL]
    )(implicit prepend: Prepend.Aux[HL, PS, Out]): Wrapper[Out[
  }
```

This approach works if the condition function will return a `Wrapper[HNil]` for situations where the function doesn't need to modify the end return type. Functions who do modify are simply free to build up their own `HList` independently.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is NOT a duplicate of [Scala double definition (2 methods have the same type erasure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307427/scala-double-definition-2-methods-have-the-same-type-erasure)

My suggestion...  Just have a single method

```
def test[Cond: TypeTag](fn: T => Cond): X = {
  if(typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Wrapper1.Condition]) ...
  else if(typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Wrapper2.Condition[_]) ...
  else ...
}
```