# In Scala all abstract types have the same type after erasure

Tags: scala, type-erasure

The following code does not compile, as both multiplication operators **have same type after erasure**: `(f: Object)Object`

I know about type erasure, but all cases I have seen had erased the **generic** type, like `List[Int]` or `List[String]`, as answered in [Scala double definition (2 methods have the same type erasure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307427/scala-double-definition-2-methods-have-the-same-type-erasure).

How can I make the Scala treat different type XxxT` types different?

```
trait AbstractTypes {
  type ScalarT
  type VectorT
  abstract class Operators(u: VectorT) {
    def *(f: ScalarT): VectorT
    def *(v: VectorT): VectorT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what [`DummyImplicit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$$DummyImplicit.html) is for:

```
trait AbstractTypes {
  type ScalarT
  type VectorT
  abstract class Operators(u: VectorT) {
    def *(f: ScalarT): VectorT
    def *(v: VectorT)(implicit dummy1: DummyImplicit): VectorT
  }
}
```

You can have any number of `DummyImplicit`s if you need more overloads whose erasure are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the tricks from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3309490/5599650) to the linked question (declaring parameter of the seconds method as call-by-name):

```scala
trait AbstractTypes {
  type ScalarT
  type VectorT
  abstract class Operators(u: VectorT) {
    def *(f: ScalarT): VectorT
    def *(v: => VectorT): VectorT
  }
}

object ConcreteTypes extends AbstractTypes {
  type ScalarT = Double
  type VectorT = Seq[Double]
  class ConcreteOperators(u: Seq[Double]) extends Operators(u) {
    def *(f: Double): Seq[Double] = u.map(_ * f)
    def *(v: => Seq[Double]): Seq[Double] = 
      (u zip v).map { case (a, b) => a * b }
  }
}

new ConcreteTypes.ConcreteOperators(Seq(2.0, 3.0, 5.0)) * 7.0 
Seq[Double] = List(14.0, 21.0, 35.0)

new ConcreteTypes.ConcreteOperators(Seq(2.0, 3.0, 5.0)) * Seq(1.0, 2.0, 3.0) 
Seq[Double] = List(2.0, 6.0, 15.0)
```

Comment: Interesting trick, but it changes the semantics a little. When you use the function instead of the value, for instance, every usage calls the function again.